# Why would the thread diameter be smaller than the drill diameter (countersink bit)

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, machining, drilling

I'm having a hard time understanding the following data for the correct sizing of countersink holes[image]

I need to make a countersink for a screw with a thread size M6 which means that, according to the table, the inner diameter d1 is 6.6mm and the outer diameter d2 is 13.7mm. However, shouldn't the diameter of the drill hole, before the tapping, be calculated using the formula: Tap Drill Size = Nominal size of the tap - pitch, meaning the tap drill size is 6 - 1 (for M6 threads) = 5? How does it make sense for the diameter of the drill hole to be bigger than the diameter of the tap hole?

Answer (score 1):

Because the countersink part of the hole is sized for the shank of the bolt, which is larger than the thread portion.

Comment: Oh, so when we do countersinking and counterboring, we don't have to tap the hole after drilling at all?

Comment: @CapBul, usually the top plate has a larger hole, a bottom plate or nut has the tapped hole: https://ruko.de/en/blog/how-to-countersink-a-screw

Comment: @CapBul You only thread the hole in the workpiece farthest from the screw head. Threading continuously through two adjacent materials is a bad idea because if you don't do it together, the threads won't line up and jamming will occur, and even if you tap the material together other complications can happen (the first thread near the top of a hole will always tear and lift and allowances need to be made for that) and it doesn't help holding strength anyways.

Comment: @CapBul I suppose one instance where you might want to tap a counterbored or countersink hole is for something like a setscrew, but that's why setscrews don't have heads to begin with.